# Use Short Date string in html textbox mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model as Follows, I am using Linq to SQL

```
public class CustomerDetails
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }

    }
```

"Customer" is populated from a single customer from the database. Customer has a field "NextEmailDate". I want to bind this to a textBox but only show the date and not the time

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Customer.NextEmailDate)
```

But I get a text box with the text 16/09/2012 00:00:00 how do I make this just 16/09/2012?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `Customer` is your actual entity, introduce a view model and pass that to your view instead. That way you can decorate it with all the formatting/validation  attributes you need e.g.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Next email date is required!")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"]
    public DateTime NextEmailDate { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CustomerDetails
{
    public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }
}
```

You can map the properties manually or use a library like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: @james - Good Solution. But How can I add a Validation to it. For range of DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

If `NextEmailDate` is a `DateTime`, you could use `NextEmailDate.ToShortDateString()`. If isn't isn't a `DateTime`, you'll have  to tell me what it is.

Comment: I don't understand why others are better since yours take into account (eventually) localization... you got my upvote!

Comment: @Tallmaris true that. Sometimes I take that for granted. Thanks for the vote!

Comment: I use this way.  Easier to change the format used on the page too, won't require the source to be compiled again.

Answer (score 2):

Add this annotation to the `NextEmailDate` property.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

Comment: Probably `dd/MM/yyyy` for `16/09`, but close enough. :)

Comment: @Mike `NextEmailDate` property isn't in the model though, its just part of the `Customer` object. How would this change the model?

Comment: @Curt, adding this annotation to that property in the `Customer` object will cause MVC to use the format when sending that property to the `TextBoxFor` extension method.

Comment: @Mike What if another property is in the `Customer` object which doesn't require this format, such as FirstName? Will this be affected?

Comment: @Curt - DataAnnotations are applied **per property** so in this case the format is only applied to the `NextEmailDate`.

Comment: @James, thanks for the help. I didn't see Curt's comment as soon as you did!

Comment: Thanks @James, I was under the impression this was being added to the `Customer` object, not the `NextEmailDate` object. This has helped clear this up for me

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.NextEmailDate, new { @Value = m.Customer.NextEmailDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know mvc 3 is tagged, but mvc 4 has additional parameter "format" for Html.TextBox

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Customer.NextEmailDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DataFim,"{0:d}", new { @class = " datepicker form-control" })
```